# Proper anotation for Array of Objects in KnockoutJS usin TypeScript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

As, DefiantelyTyped types' definiitons were updated to use TypeSctipt with Generics, what would be the proper type in the definition (as now only ObservableArray of T is must):

```
class Some { 
  name: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable("Some name"),
  arrayOfValues: KnockoutObservableArray< (of Object??? ) > ???? ;

  constructor () {
    arrayOfValues.push( {key: "value"} );
    ...
```

Comment: The type of what you have in your array. You can use Any.

Answer (score 4):

You can use TypeScript's type inference for this, as otherwise you'll end up with a long line of code that repeats itself quite a bit:

```
var examples = ko.observableArray<Example>();
examples.push(new Example('Test'));
examples.push('Type warning'); // not an 'Example'
```

In this example, you pass the type argument when you create the `ko.observableArray`. TypeScript infers that `var examples` is of type `KnockoutObservableArray<Example>` and checks all of your calls.

To put it into context, here is the code with your example:

```
interface YourType {
    key: string;
}

class Some { 
    name = ko.observable<string>("Some name");
    arrayOfValues = ko.observableArray<YourType>();

    constructor () {
        this.arrayOfValues.push( {key: "value"} );
        ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
KnockoutObservableArray<any>
```

or define a interface for your type.